# Set option default value based on build type in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a project where a bunch of configuration options exist that can be used to control the compiled source code by setting preprocessor flags. Some of them enable code with better performance.

Now, I would like to enable a CMake option per default if the build-type is set to release.

Minimal example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(foo)

option(FOO_OPT "Enabled by default when building with RELEASE" (OFF IF DEBUG / ON IF RELEASE)

message(STATUS "Value: ${FOO_OPT}")
```

Now, I wish to get the following output:

```
$cmake path/to/source -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
[...]
-- Value: ON
[...]
```

```
$cmake path/to/source -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
[...]
-- Value: OFF
[...]
```

If I remember correctly, explicitly checking `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is a bad idea and should be avoided (Issue with multi-config generators like vs-studio).

Is there a recommended way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not set a default value of the option depending on `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` without checking it.

Well, you could assign to the variable a generator expression like

```
$<IF:$<CONFIG:Release>,ON,OFF>
```

but you cannot use this value in `if` statements, because generator expressions are expanded only at the end of the configuration process.

Instead, you may define an **additional value** for the option, which **denotes** something special, and make this value to be the default one:

```
# Declare a parameter with 3 possible values:
#   ON - the option is set,
#   OFF - the option is unset,
#   ReleaseOnly - the option is set only in Release build.
set(FOO_OPT "ReleaseOnly" CACHE STRING "Use foo feature (ON/OFF/ReleaseOnly)")
set_property(CACHE FOO_OPT PROPERTY STRINGS ON OFF ReleaseOnly)
```

When generate a compiler options according to this parameter, you could use following snippet:

```
# Prepare foo_compiler_opt variable according to FOO_OPT.
if(FOO_OPT STREQUAL "ReleaseOnly")
  set(foo_compiler_opt "$<IF:$<CONFIG:Release>,--foo,--bar>")
elif (FOO_OPT)
  set(foo_compiler_opt "--foo")
else ()
  set(foo_compiler_opt "--bar")
endif()
# Use foo_compiler_opt in a place which allows a generator expression.
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE ${foo_compiler_opt})
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late, but this fixed my problem, thank you very much